# .htaccess Rewrite rule conflict with other file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have made a .htaccess file but a problem occurs is that conflicting with other file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^f9/([^/\.]+)?$ footer_arts.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^f10/([^/\.]+)?$     footer_bus.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^f11/([^/\.]+)?$     footer_cely.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^f12/([^/\.]+)?$     footer_com.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^f13/([0-9]+)$     footer_edu.php?page=$1
```

when i open www.example.com/f9/1 its open perfectly , but when i open www.example.com/f10/1 or www.example.com/f11/1 it shows another page which is in my htaccess file just like f13/1, how can i prevent this conflicting and open correct page

Comment: any help from all that helps me alot and thanks

Comment: Can't really help unless you show us what it's conflicting with. ^^

Comment: ok i will edit the question

Comment: i edit the question just check

Comment: so when you try and access `/f10/1` where does it take you?

Comment: it takes me on /f13/1

Comment: i dont understand why this happened

Comment: i m newbie in .htaccess

Comment: i really need help Jon :)

Comment: Is that your entire `.htaccess`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91646/discussion-between-amy-and-jon).

Answer (score 2):

Try your code this way.

```
RewriteEngine On
#if the request is a real file or directory, do nothing otherwise process one of the rules below.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^f9/([^/]+)/?$ footer_arts.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^f10/([^/]+)/?$ footer_bus.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^f11/([^/]+)/?$ footer_cely.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^f12/([^/]+)/?$ footer_com.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^f13/([0-9]+)/?$ footer_edu.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: same problem occurs ... help me panama

Comment: nope bro ..why should i downvote u gave me a special time of yours

Comment: Do you have other rules in the .htaccess? And did you clear your browser cache? Or Try it in another browser window.

Comment: if u know dude then plz help me i m really needy at this time

Comment: Not just another window, but another browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91650/discussion-between-amy-and-panama-jack).